# Volley service is running on emulator correctly but not on real device.? I have also change localhost to my IP address

Tags: android

Volley service is running on emulator correctly but not on real device? I have also change localhost to my IP address?

I have also tried for increasing volley request time but still not solved with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to be more specific with the question.

If you are using local host
- just try to connect the phone to the computer and try to compile the app check its working or not

- try to access the url from the browser check its accessible

Comment: yes i have tried it but not working and in my ulr insted of localhost i have used my computer ip address but still not working

Comment: just put 10.0.2.2 insted of local host when you try with phone connected to computer

Comment: @PravinKumbhar hi did you found the solution for this problem. because i am facing the same problem my volley request is working fine on emulator but facing following ERROR on real device :                                                                                
W/System.err: com.android.volley.TimeoutError at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:173) etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will run your app on device connected.

1. Enable USB debugging on your device by going to **Settings > Developer options**.
2. click on `run` and `select your device`.

Comment: i did this before but still not getting response from volley service

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the URL that you are sending requests to.

If you have your device connected to your system via USB, try

`http://10.0.2.2/myserverfile.php`

else if your server is somewhere hosted online, use `http://www.myserverlocation.blah/myserverfile.php`